# Pandas: How do I obtain the difference between dates and add them to a new data frame?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a main data frame called `df` which contains many columns, including `shipment_date` and `order_date`. I want to create a new data frame that contains only `order_date` and the difference.

I've calculated the difference:

```
df_ship_diff = df['shipment_date'] - df['order_date']
```

How do I create a title for df_ship_diff? And how do I create a new data frame with `df_ship_diff` and `order_date`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
df_ship_diff = df.copy()[["order_date"]]
df_ship_diff["title"] = df['shipment_date'] - df['order_date']

# To add other columns :
# df_ship_diff["new_col"] = Something
```

Comment: This gives the difference in a data frame: 

df_ship_diff = pd.DataFrame()
df_ship_diff['shipment_days'] = df['shipment_date'] - df['order_date']

Should I use merge to add `order_date ` to this or is there an easier way?

Comment: you can make `order_date` index in df ,  try `df.set_index("order_date" , inplace=True)`

Comment: Suppose I don't want to make it an index, how do I add another column from df, namely order_date?

Comment: How do I keep adding columns? Suppose I want to add another column called `seller` to this new data frame?